# Shell script Permission denied mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write only in Cron

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, cron

I have a simple sh file to backup some MySql databases and FTP them to an external server.
The shell script works fine if called from a command line, but doesn't work when scheduled as cron job.

All the files are chmdod 777

This is the script

```
mysqldump -uuser-ppassword databasename | gzip > shop1.gz
mysqldump -uuser -password databasename | gzip > shop2.gz
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword databasename | gzip > timesheets.gz
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword databasename | gzip > library.gz 
tar -cvvf backup.tar *.gz

filename="backup.tar"
hostname="****"
username="****"
password="****"
ftp -un $hostname <<EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password
passive
cd db_backups
binary
put $filename
quit
EOF
```

I got the errors:

```
httpdocs/dump/db_bck.sh: line 1: shop1.gz: Permission denied
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
httpdocs/dump/db_bck.sh: line 2: shop2.gz: Permission denied
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
httpdocs/dump/db_bck.sh: line 3: timesheets.gz: Permission denied
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
httpdocs/dump/db_bck.sh: line 4: library.gz: Permission denied
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
tar: backup.tar: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
ftp: u: unknown option
```

THIS IS THE FINAL WORKING SCRIPT, JUST IN CASE WOULD BE USEFUL TO SOMEONE ELSE:

```
mysqldump -u -p mydb1 | gzip > httpdocs/dump/mydb1.gz
mysqldump -u -p mydb2 | gzip > httpdocs/dump/mydb2.gz
mysqldump -u -p mydb3 | gzip > httpdocs/dump/mydb3.gz
mysqldump -u -p mydb4 | gzip > httpdocs/dump/mydb4.gz 


cd /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/dump
filename="*.gz"
hostname="ftphostname"
username="ftpusernam"
password="ftppassword"
/usr/kerberos/bin/ftp -un $hostname <<EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password
passive
cd db_backups
binary
prompt
mput $filename
quit
EOF
```

Comment: Please check the user from whom you are running cron job has access to use mysql.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The user is the same I use from the command line.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52769/cron-job-permission-denied-creating-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the following (preliminary checks)

1. Make sure you have enough free disk space.
2. Increase [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_max_allowed_packet) for mysqldump
3. Permission of the user running the cron (check everything `chown`, `chgrp`, `chmod`)
4. Make sure gzip is is actually working
5. Ensure you have have write permissions for the `filename="backup.tar"`
6. Try to use **full path** information like (/var/lib/mysql/backups/shop2.gz)
7. Lastly use `touch` to create the file first, and then run the script using cron

Comment: Good check list. I'll follow your suggestions as soon as I have time and I'll come back to you. Thanks !

Comment: It was a path issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and had also already chmodded the files to 777. Resolved it by putting in the full path for the gzip file.